# How to active selected image on load Galleria

Tags: jquery, image, galleria

For exam, i've got 10 images. And i use Galleria fullscreen in full content. And get this images thumbnail on front page.

```
ul id="galleria">
        <li><img src="photo1.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="photo2.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="photo3.jpg"></li>
     // more...
    </ul>
```

When i click frontpage thumbnails (exam, 3. thumbnail), open that fullscreen images. So, i click 3. images, open 3. images in fullscreen.

I know, Galleria have [show option](http://galleria.io/docs/options/show/) but i don't know how can i do dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic? You wan to use button "Next", "Back"? Its simple way to use themes from developers.
Dynamic array of Image for Galleria:
http://galleria.io/docs/options/dataSource/
You need just load this array from folder/base with ajax or php-script